# Implement numerical sorting for html table?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

Could someone help me modify this code to support numerical sorting. Currently it only supports sorting alphabetically and I'm not a js writer myself, i found this online. I only need it to sort numerical, not alphabetical.

bonus: would it be possible to make it support numbers and strings

Here is the working link of it sorting alphabetical. [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/JokerMartini/oqr0mjc6/1/)

Thank you.

```
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function () {makeAllSortable();};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working in both string and numbers

```
if(!isNaN(a.cells[col].textContent) && !isNaN(b.cells[col].textContent))
        return reverse * ((+a.cells[col].textContent) - (+b.cells[col].textContent))
       return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oqr0mjc6/3/

Comment: The problem of this approach is that `"2" < "10" < "10a" < "2"` i.e. transitivity doesn't hold. Sorting using a non-transitive criteria is madness.

Comment: hey @Man Programmer would you be able to convert this https://jsfiddle.net/JokerMartini/ctq3w7sj/ you helped me with, so it uses jquery and not pure complex javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the comparison code to

```
return reverse * ((+a.cells[col].textContent) - (+b.cells[col].textContent))
```

the unary `+` in Javascript can be used to convert a string to its numeric value.

Sorting a single column that can contain both numbers and non-numbers is trickier because you need to establish a transitive sorting criteria... for example:

- all number-like strings come before other strings
- number-like strings are sorted according to numeric value
- other strings are sorted alphabetically

in code:

```
function xcmp(a, b) {
    if (isNan(a)) {
       if (isNan(b)) {
           return a.localeCompare(b);
       } else {
           return +1; // a non-numeric, b numeric: a > b
       }
    } else {
       if (isNan(b)) {
           return -1; // a numeric, b non-numeric: a < b
       } else {
           return a - b;
       }
    }
}
```

Simpler criteria like "compare them as numbers if both are numbers and as strings otherwise" don't work well because

- "2" < "10"
- "10" < "10a"
- "10a" < "2"

i.e. you can create logical "loops" for which the very concept of sorting doesn't make sense.

Comment: would there be a way to make the item work with both numbers and strings?

Comment: @JokerMartini: html cannot contain numbers... it's all text. Do you mean saying that both `"10" > "2"` but `"abc" < "bcd"`? What about the string `"10,000,000"` ? is it a number ?

Answer (score 0):

In your sort function you can try to transform the `a.cells[col].textContent.trim()`  into a number. If it is not a number you compare it lexiografically, otherwise you compare the numbers