# Basic sorting of a table once by one column in one direction (desc) without a plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

I have a basic table with x amount of columns.
The table needs to be sorted by the value in the first column which is an integer.
The sort only needs to happen once in descending order using jQuery or JavaScript without a plug-in.

```
Position   Event
3          Investigation
5          Triage
4          Clinic
1          MDT
2          Other
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement numerical sorting for html table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480140/implement-numerical-sorting-for-html-table)

Comment: @HereticMonkey that dupe is not super applicable. It is for sure more complex/verbose/old fashioned than my answer here

Comment: @mplungjan "old fashioned" is irrelevant; if you have a "new fashioned" answer to that question, add the answer to that question. Your answer here essentially duplicates the answer on that question; namely, use unary `+` to coerce the value to a number and subtract. There are many, many, other duplicates to choose from, if one were not looking to answer the question.

Comment: I can add it to another dupe. The one posted isn’t ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some spreads ('...') and a simple sort function

Inner spread is to make the rows sortable and outer spread is to change them back to html

The unary `+` is not even needed here because of subtraction (ascending numerical)

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  const tb = document.getElementById("tb");
  const rows = tb.querySelectorAll("tr")
  tb.append(...[...rows].sort((a,b) => {
    const A = +a.querySelector("td").textContent;
    const B = +b.querySelector("td").textContent;
    return A-B;
  })) 
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Event</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Investigation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Triage</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Clinic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>MDT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Other</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```